# How does the Kalman Filter actually work?

Tags: forecasting, kalman-filter

I know that the Kalman filter can be used whenever we have a measurement and transition equation. I also know that the Kalman filter can handle missing data. From my course at university, I know that Kalman filters are used all the time to make GDP forecasts.

What I don't know is how the Kalman filter actually does this. I know how the HP filter works and I guess that both approaches are similar. Does someone know exactly how it works and can explain it, please?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Kalman filter** is a mathematical method used to **estimate the state of a system based on noisy, indirect measurements**. It consists of two steps: ***prediction*** and ***update***.

In the **prediction** step, the **Kalman filter** uses the system's transition model *to predict the state at the next time step based on the current state and any control inputs*. The transition model is a mathematical representation of how the system is expected to evolve over time.

In the **update** step, the **Kalman filter** uses the measurement model *to incorporate new information from the measurements into the prediction*. The measurement model is a mathematical representation of how the system's state is related to the measurements.

An intuitive explanation of the **Kalman filter** can be found here

- [An Explanation of the Kalman Filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/848776/787560)
- [How a Kalman filter works, in pictures](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/)
- [kalman filter: understanding the mathematical part](https://mathoverflow.net/q/39074)